# keras model using intermediate layers as inputs and outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a basic LSTM autoencoder in Keras (Tensoflow backend). The structure of the model is as follows:

```
l0 = Input(shape=(10, 2))
l1 = LSTM(16, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(l0)
l2 = LSTM(8, activation='relu', return_sequences=False)(l1)
l3 = RepeatVector(10)(l2)
l4 = LSTM(8, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(l3)
l5 = LSTM(16, activation='relu', return_sequences=True)(l4)
l6 = TimeDistributed(Dense(2))(l5)
```

I can extract and compile the encoder and the autoencoder as follows:

```
encoder = Model(l0, l2)
auto_encoder = Model(l0, l6)
auto_encoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])
```

However when I try to make a model out of intermediate layers such as:

```
decoder = Model(inputs=l3, outputs=l6)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_12:0", shape=(?, 10, 2), dtype=float32) at layer "input_12". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

I don't understand how `l3` and `l6` are disconnected with respect to each other! I also tried to make the decoder using `get_layer(...).input` and `get_layer(...).output` but it throws he same error.

An explanation would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that there is no input layer for the model you are trying to create with:

`decoder = Model(inputs=l3, outputs=l6)`

You could create one by producing a new `Input()` layer with the correct shape then accessing each of your existing layers. Something like this:

```py
input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))
l3 = auto_encoder.layers[3](input_layer)
l4 = auto_encoder.layers[4](l3)
l5 = auto_encoder.layers[5](l4)
l6 = auto_encoder.layers[6](l5)

decoder = Model(input_layer, l6)
decoder.summary()
```

```
Model: "model_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_14 (InputLayer)        [(None, 8)]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_2 (RepeatVecto (None, 10, 8)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_12 (LSTM)               (None, 10, 8)             544       
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_13 (LSTM)               (None, 10, 16)            1600      
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_1 (TimeDist (None, 10, 2)             34        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,178
Trainable params: 2,178
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine. If I fit the `auto_encoder` will I be able to to use the decoder right away? Since the structure is `functional` the weights from the `auto_encoder` will be shared automatically?

Comment: @tachyon yes, that's right. The weights of the layers used in both models are shared

Comment: Instead of `input_layer = Input(shape=(8,))` would it be convinient to use `input_layer = Input(tensor=encoding_layer)`? That way I don't have to explicitly calculate shape.